# Receiving money on a Wise USD account from a US bank via bill.com for a non-US resident

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, swift

Some companies use bill.com to pay their contractors.

Bill.com website states this:

> Note: To successfully receive a payment by a Bill.com customer will
> have to meet the following criteria:
>
> - Your personal or business address must be within the United States  or Puerto Rico
> - Your corporation, partnership, or other organization must
>   be organized under the laws of the United States.
>
> If you don't meet
> these conditions, you can still receive a payment via Bill.com
> international payments. Please contact your customer to set up
> international payments through Bill.com.

When you open a USD account in Wise (previously TransferWise), it gives you two types of details:

- To receive USD from bank accounts inside the US (has a routing number).
- To receive USD from bank accounts outside the US (has a SWIFT number).

Both types of details provide a US address. However Wise's headquarters are located in the UK.

How therefore can a company pay via bill.com to a Wise USD bank account of a non-US resident? Will a local transfer via a routing number not work, because it's not an international payment?

Will it then be possible to send money from a US bank to a Wise USD account (which shows a US address) via SWIFT? Also when revealing the SWIFT number for the Wise USD account it says:

> We’ll return payments from countries **not** on this list to the sender.

The list includes the United States. Does it mean that SWIFT payments from a US bank to a Wise USD account are possible?

If the previous ways aren't possible, would it then be possible to receive USD (converted to Euro) from a US bank to a Wise Euro account (which shows a Belgian address)? This would be an international payment.

If all or several of these ways are possible, which one then would be the best?

Comment: I'm finding your question confusing. In the middle, you have "_How therefore can a company pay via bill.com to a Wise USD bank account of a non-US resident?_" Is this something you _know can happen_, and you are asking for an explanation of _how_ it can happen? Or are you asking _if_ it can happen?

Comment: @TripeHound I think, both. I'm wondering if it's possible at all, and if so, what is the best way to do it. Or if some other way is strongly recommended.

Comment: @the_cool_mind did you solve this issue? I’m having the same situation

Comment: @DenisOmerovic no, we ended up using a different payment provider instead of bill.com. I'm not sure if it could've been solved.